# How can I get the Volume Serial Number of a FAT volume?

Tags: mac, fat32

I need to programatically get the Volume Serial Number of a FAT volume (for example, a USB drive or removable SD card) in mac OS. Do you know of any program with which to do it? (Bonus points for a Python API call!)

To clarify, I'm asking for the hyphenated 8-hex-digit number that is displayed by the `vol` command in DOS:

```
C:\>vol e:
Volume in Drive E is MYSDCARD
Volume Serial Number is E432-EF79
```

`E432-EF79` is the VSN I'm looking for. It may sometimes be referred to as a UUID, though it's not 128 bits long.

On Mac I can mount the drive, and get its volume name, using commands like `df`. I can inspect it in DiskUtility, and see things like capacity and device name. But how do I get the VSN?

Answer (score 1):

For a **FAT32** formatted *disk*, in **Terminal**, the following example *compound command* will output its **volume serial number**:

```bash
var="$(sudo dd if=/dev/diskNs1 skip=67 bs=1 count=4 2>/dev/null | hexdump -e '4/4 "%X"')"; echo "${var:0:${#var}/2}-${var:${#var}/2}"
```

- Replace `N` in `/dev/diskNs1` with the correct *disk number*.

  - You can use the `mount` *command* or `diskutil list` to ascertain the *disk number* of the *target disk*.
- Note that the *target disk* needs to first be unmounted before running the example *compound command*.

Assuming the *target disk* is mounted as `/dev/disk6s1`, in **Terminal** use:

```bash
diskutil unmountDisk disk6
```

After the *target disk* is unmounted, then use:

```bash
var="$(sudo dd if=/dev/disk6s1 skip=67 bs=1 count=4 2>/dev/null | hexdump -e '4/4 "%X"')"; echo "${var:0:${#var}/2}-${var:${#var}/2}"
```

For my *test disk*, a **USB** *flash drive* formatted **FAT32**, the output was:

```
18E4-4FA7
```

I confirmed this with the `vol` *command* in **Windows** and the `blkid` *command* in **Linux**, and the output of `vol` and `blkid` matched the output of the example *compound command* above.

---

**Notes:**

With **FAT32** *volumes*, the **Volume Serial Number** is stored in the **Boot Sector** at *offset* **67** (**0x43**), and is four *bytes* long.

Interesting Reading: [Volume Serial Numbers
and Format Date/Time Verification](https://www.digital-detective.net/documents/Volume%20Serial%20Numbers.pdf)

There may be a way to format the output of the `dd` *command* with `hexdump` to avoid the rest of the *compound command*, however, I didn't want to take the time to figure it out and chose to use *parameter expansion* and *shell arithmetic* instead for the final formatting.

Comment: Wow, this is impressive. I tested it, and it worked for me. I wish my program wouldn't have to have root access and unmount the disk in order to get this info, but that may not be possible. You've given me a way to do it (and proven the results) when I had no way before.

Answer (score 1):

#### Q: "how do I get the VSN?"

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number) indicates the FAT VSN is based on the RTC in the system used to create or format the disk. Interestingly, [it's said that](http://www.brettglass.com/ttr19980206a.html) Microsoft & IBM created the VSN to keep up with an early innovation by Apple!

As you've suggested, it seems that the the label `UUID` is used in some systems instead of `VSN` - e.g. this seems to be the case with the `lsblk` utility widely used in most Linux/Unix systems. However, macOS (specifically the `diskutil` tool) uses a ["true" 128-bit UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for FAT volumes. For FAT volumes then, there are two methods for creating a "unique" identifier. Intuitively, it seems that the 128-bit UUID is much more likely to be "unique" than the VSN.

You've indicated your preference for the VSN in your question, and that may be "unique enough" for your application. However, given that there doesn't seem to be any readily available tools for macOS to **easily** extract the VSN (`vol` for macOS :), you may wish to consider an alternative:

**Step 1: Get the device name**

```
% DEVNM=`diskutil list | grep FAT | grep -o "disk[0-9]s[0-9]"`
% echo $DEVNM
disk4s1
```

**Step 2: Get the UUID (EDITED)**

Using macOS' `diskutil` piped through `grep` with a regular expression will output the 128-bit UUID:

```
% diskutil info "$DEVNM" | grep "Volume UUID:" | grep -o '[0-9A-Z]*-[0-9A-Z]*-[0-9A-Z]*-[0-9A-Z]*-[0-9A-Z]*'
74453B21-2067-3766-8A2D-EA0AC27F99A8
```

**Alternatively:**

- You asked about a `Python API call`:

  - [the `uuid.py` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) may be useful generating UUIDs (perhaps for use in Windows?)
  - [The Python FAT Reader project](https://github.com/andrsv/Python-FAT-reader) may be useful for extracting VSNs from FAT volumes, but it seems to use `dd` which will (inconveniently) require the volume be unmounted.
- The article [Get FAT Drive Serial Numbers in Unix](https://www.kirsle.net/get-fat-drive-serial-numbers-in-unix) has a good walk-through & explanation with a CLI for fetching a VSN from several FAT variants. It's similar to [another answer here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408570/149366)
- If the drive is `exFAT`, you can use this:

  ```
  % sudo newfs_exfat -N disk3s1 | grep Volume Serial
  ```

  Unfortunately, `newfs_msdos` doesn't have a facility for outputting the VSN.

Comment: 1. The first _command_ in **Step 1: Get the device name** errors with `zsh: command not found: list` because you did not include appropriate _command substitution_. 2. In **Step 2: Get the UUID**, the `Volume UUID:` of the `diskutil info` _command_ **is not** the same as the **Volume Serial Number** of a **FAT32** formatted drive. -- For my test disk, in **Linux**, the `blkid` _command_ outputs e.g. `/dev/sdb1: LABEL="DATA" UUID="18E4-4FA7" TYPE="vfat"` and in **macOS**, the `Volume UUID:` of the `diskutil info` _command_ outputs e.g. `E92BA062-FB92-3473-825C-DF7102F7226E`

Comment: Which parses to `E92BA062-F`, `B92-3`, `473-8` and `25C-D` with your `grep` _command_. So is not really clear how you ended up with `5966-39BF`. AFAICT `diskutil info` does not or does not consistently output the **Volume Serial Number** of a **FAT32** formatted drive. With **FAT32** _volumes_, the **Volume Serial Number** is stored in the **Boot Sector** at _offset_ **67** (**0x43**), and is four _bytes_ long.

Comment: AFAICT In **macOS**, it has to be read at the disk level using e.g. `dd` and then be properly formatted to produce the same results as on **Windows** or **Linux** using the `vol` and `blkid` _commands_, respectively. In my testing `diskutil info` does read the four _bytes_ starting at _offset_ **67** (**0x43**) in the **Boot Sector** of my **FAT32** formatted **USB** drive.

Comment: @Seamus In my testing, the volume UUID produced by diskutil was `09181F6D-2A59-3A51-AC79-B0F0EA862CB8`, and parsing it with the regexps you suggested does not produce anything that matches the format of a VSN. In other words, user3439894 is right.

Comment: @user3439894 "In my testing `diskutil info` does read the four bytes starting at offset 67 (0x43)..." So you think diskutil can give us the VSN? Or did you mean "**doesn't** read"?

Comment: @LarsH, I meant to say **does not**; however I also meant it in the context of explicitly the four _bytes_ starting at _offset_ **67** (**0x43**). That said it **does** read the first **4096** _bytes_ of the disk (and more). However, I have yet to see `diskutil` parse any of what it reads into a valid **MS-DOS FAT32 Volume Serial Number** that produces the same _value_ for the same device read under **Windows** and or **Linux** using the `vol` and `blkid` _commands_ respectively against the method in my answer, that matches the same _value_ all around for the same device under all 3 **OSes**.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes - apologies for the error. I *assumed* that macOS rendered UUIDs for FAT filesystems same as the rest of the Unix/Linux world - this was a faulty assumption. I've made some changes that hopefully have corrected this, and verified it works on my macOS 10.15.6 system. Please let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Seamus, Your original answer, nor the subsequent edits you've made, produce an **MS-DOS FAT32 Volume Serial Number**! In **macOS**, the **Volume UUID** presented by `diskutil info` for a **FAT32** formatted disk **is not** at all the same thing as as an **MS-DOS FAT32 Volume Serial Number**, or what under **Linux** is equivalent to the value of **UUID** presented for a **FAT32** formatted disk. As your answer **does not** actually answer the question asked, which is **How can I get the Volume Serial Number of a FAT volume?**, you should consider deleting it.

Comment: @user3439894: The OP stated the VSN **aka `UUID`**. I answered for UUID as an alternative. And since the application is unknown, it's not entirely clear that what you've "extracted" is actually a VSN - it's easy to "spoof" a VSN.

Comment: Seamus, I asked specifically for the VSN -- which "may sometimes be referred to as a UUID, though it's not 128 bits long." In other words, any true, 128-bit UUID is not the VSN, and is not what I need.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, you did. And I provided at least one solution that provided that. Sorry my answer didn't help you.

Comment: I was responding to your assertion that I had asked for "VSN aka UUID". That was misleading, hence the correction. Yes, your later edits did offer some links to solutions that use `dd` to extract the VSN. Thank you for those.

Comment: @LarsH: It was not my intent to misquote or mislead. I wrote `VSN aka UUID` - which was intended as a [**shorthand**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand) of sorts for what you actually did write. But I've apologized - I hope you can accept that, and let's drop this - shall we?

Comment: I've done the same thing at times -- used a shorthand that, contrary to my intent, sounded like it meant something different from what was actually the case. It's hard to gauge intent through comments. Part of my reason for clarifying VSN vs. UUID is that there is a lot of confusion out there between them, which makes it easy for developers to end up writing to the wrong requirements. Thanks again for your work on this answer. It may well help someone, even if it's not what I need.

Comment: Yes we can drop it as far as I'm concerned.